# Logstash add date field to logs

Tags: logstash

My application produces logs, without a timestamp. 
Is there a way in logstash to append timestamp to the logs on processing

something like,

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{date}" }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logstash adds a `@timestamp` field by default. You don't need to set anything additional. Logstash will take the time an event is received and add the field for you.

For example if you try this command:

```
LS_HOME/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin {} } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }'
```

You will see an automatically created `@timestamp` field in your result:

```
"@timestamp": "2015-07-13T17:41:13.174Z"
```

You can change the format and timezone using the [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) or you can match a timestamp of your event (e.g. a syslog timestamp) using other filters like grok or json.

Comment: Thanks @hurb. I missed that out.